# email headers do not show normal ip

Tags: email, smtp-headers

I am learning about mail servers, since the mail I send is not received by Hotmail. So I'm comparing mail headers from different sources to find out what could be my problem. I now have a very basic question. In the email headers I normally see this part:

Received: from blabla.xx.xx.net ([ip.ip.ip.ip])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP ....

However, in the mail I send, I do not see the correct ip adres, but a very long number/string separated by colons, like this:

Received: from xx.xx.xx.net ([3201:7c8:xxxx:2de:xxxx:4dc3:xxxx:bf40])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP ....

What does this mean? Why do I not see a normal ip address?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That looks like it might be an IPv6 address, though it's difficult to tell since you have mangled it.